# Is it possible to hide or remove the keyboard when touching a textfield

Tags: xcode, keyboard, uitextfield

I have created a custom keyboard that can be moved around the iPad screen. I wish to use this keyboard in lieu of the default or optional keyboards associated with textfields. In particular, I don't want the default or optional keyboards to show up at the bottom of the screen.

My custom, movable keyboard has numerical keys as well as buttons for Previous, Next, Erase, and Done. To move from one textfield to the next involves changing the first responder, but this always causes the default or optional keyboards to become visible and active. This is not what I wish to do.

Is it possible to use my movable keyboard in lieu of the standard keyboards?

Answer (score 0):

I've decided that Apple doesn't allow hiding or removing any keyboard. So, instead of using UITextField for data entry, I'm opting for UILabel. I can create all the same functionality with the added benefit of building my own keypad that can be placed anywhere I want and is movable as well.